# Rails find_by_email multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

I am working on a rails application and i have 3 different user types. These users are potentially very different, so i created models for each of them. Now, they should be able to login thru a single form. So basically i want to say something like 'find_by_email("some_email")', but search over all three tables. It seems, though, that Rails expect you to call 'find_by' with a specific model, like Admin.find_by(). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this and assuming that that the email is unique across all the tables

```
[Model1, Model2, Model3].each do |model|
  break if model.find_by_email("email@email.com").present?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is early in your development, but the current structure may not be the best possible route. How many different columns are NOT shared by each of the user types? You may want to use a "user role" system, and have that simply be an extra column on your user table.

Than, you can use something like [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) to manage those roles and what/where they may access.

Comment: i actually did it that way to begin with, and it worked fine. However, i am a bit concerned that it will be a problem in the future. I have an idea that the various users might end up pretty different. What would be the benefits of keeping with the simpler approach?

Comment: I would say that the data structure is more correct. As there is really one list of user's and they just have different roles on your site/app. Also, with something such as CanCan, it become programmatically easier to assign roles in a bottom up manner.

I admit, it can be preference, but i'd think it'd be easier to manage in the long run.

`User.where(email: "email address", role: "admin")`

Comment: Yeah, i think i will actually stick with this technique. I can't really figure out what the "best" way is. Since STI worked well enough in the first place, i'll stick with that. Probably gonna regret both techniques anyways :)